# Use Django's models in a Scrapy project (in the pipeline)

Tags: python, django, django-models, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

This has been asked before but the answer that always comes up is to use [DjangoItem](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem). However it states on it's github that:

> often not a good choice for a write intensive applications (such as a web crawler) ... may not scale well

This is the crux of my problem, I'd like to use and interact with my django model in the same way I can when I run ***python manage.py shell*** and I do ***from myapp.models import Model1***. Using queries [like seen here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/)

I have tried relative imports and moving my whole scrapy project inside my django app, both to no avail.

Where should I move my scrapy project to for this to work? How can I recreate / use all the methods that are available to me in the shell inside a scrapy pipeline?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: No I have not. It's driving me crazy. I'd really like to avoid dealing with raw SQL. The Django api is great for that! I might look into sqlalchemy but i'd rather not learn another library if I don't have too. Do you have any suggestions or possibly an approach I could look into?

Comment: OK I have done this before. Will write down the answer soon. It's a weekend.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In here i have create a sample project which uses scrapy inside django. And uses Django models and ORM in the one of the pipelines.

https://github.com/bipul21/scrapy_django

The directory structure starts with your django project. 
In this case the the project name is **django_project**. 
Once inside the base project you create your scrapy project i.e. **scrapy_project** here

In your scrapy project settings add the following line to setup initialize django

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), ".."))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

django.setup()
```

In the pipeline i have made a simple query to Question Model

```
from questions.models import Questions

class ScrapyProjectPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            question = Questions.objects.get(identifier=item["identifier"])
            print "Question already exist"
            return item
        except Questions.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        question = Questions()
        question.identifier = item["identifier"]
        question.title = item["title"]
        question.url = item["url"]
        question.save()
        return item
```

You can check in the project for any further details like model schema.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! thank you so much. I cant believe i couldn't find this online.

Comment: So if this works, what's the point of the Scrapy-DjangoItem plugin? This seems better, since I'd need to make queries to the db as well to properly update/save the scraped items

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie did you find anything about django-items plugin?