# Using Django's app model in scrapy pipeline gives 'Apps aren't loaded yet' exception

Tags: django, django-models, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I want to use Django's(version-2.2) Model in scrapy's pipeline.py. I followed these links,

1. https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e
2. [Use Django's models in a Scrapy project (in the pipeline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905464/use-djangos-models-in-a-scrapy-project-in-the-pipeline)

and added line 'django.setup()' in settings.py of scrpay project.
It gives me following error,

```
File "D:\Technologies\Python_Code\django_develops\django_development\kumo_soft\findchipsData\..\inventory\models.py", line 7, in <module>
  class Product(models.Model):
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in _new_
  new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 304, in add_to_class
  value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
  self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\__init_.py", line 33, in _getattr_
  return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in _getitem_
  backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
  return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\importlib\__init_.py", line 126, in import_module
  return bootstrap.gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "c:\program files (x86)\lib\site-packages\django-2.2-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
  ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says what you have to do.

Since your Django project is configured to use MySQL as a backing database, you'll need to install the `mysqlclient` package (with e.g. `pip install mysqlclient`) in the environment you're running your Scrapy project in.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question.Your solution helped me.I had issue while mysqlclient installation on windows 10, 64 bit.but bellow link heled me 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146117/installing-mysqlclient-in-python-3-6-in-windows' .